# Make XslCompiledTransform ignore scripts

Tags: c#, xml, exception, xslt

Have an XSL file which contains starts with the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:XQHeaderFunc="java:com.sonicsw.xq.service.xform.HeaderExtension"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="XQHeaderFunc saxon">

    <saxon:script language="java" implements-prefix="XQHeaderFunc" src="java:com.sonicsw.xq.service.xform.HeaderExtension" />
```

And later in the file:

```
<xsl:variable name="processId" select="XQHeaderFunc:getProperty(XQHeaderFunc:new(),'processId',-1)" />
```

When I try to do a transformation now I get this error:

> Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'java:com.sonicsw.xq.service.xform.HeaderExtension'.

This is some SonicMQ specific stuff that I don't care about. Is there a way I can just ignore it somehow?

---

I currently do the transformation like this:

```
var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document,
    IgnoreWhitespace = true,
    IgnoreComments = true,
    IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true,
    CheckCharacters = true,
};

var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document,
    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
    NewLineChars = "\r\n",
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "  ",
    CloseOutput = false,
};

var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached);
using (var stylesheet = XmlReader.Create(xslFile, readerSettings))
    xsl.Load(stylesheet);

using (var result = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var xml = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, readerSettings))
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(result, writerSettings))
    {
        xsl.Transform(xml, xmlWriter);
    }

    // Deal with result
}
```

Comment: What should happen instead of the script function?

Comment: Probably nothing, although would be nice if I could inject a value so I could insert a hardcoded string instead for example.

Comment: Preprocess the xslt (possibly with another xslt) to remove/rewrite the stylesheet the way you want to be...

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem? @Svish

Comment: @Chris Have a feeling I didn't, but can't quite remember. Most likely I gave up on this small project as there were fires to put out :P (working for a different client now, so can't go back and check either...)

Answer (score 0):

Is the XSLT file supplied dynamically or is it a single file that you can hand-modify?

If it's the latter, you can use this to prevent the custom function from causing an error:

```
<xsl:variable name="processId">
  <xsl:if test="function-available('XQHeaderFunc:getProperty') and function-available('XQHeaderFunc:new)">
    <xsl:value-of select="XQHeaderFunc:getProperty(XQHeaderFunc:new(),'processId',-1)" />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

This would result in processId being blank if the functions were not available.  To substitute a default value, you could do this

```
<xsl:variable name="processId">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="function-available('XQHeaderFunc:getProperty') and function-available('XQHeaderFunc:new)">
      <xsl:value-of select="XQHeaderFunc:getProperty(XQHeaderFunc:new(),'processId',-1)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      Default Value
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```